# How can I redirect to my website from Facebook App sharing

Tags: facebook

Could anyone help me when I press on my Facebook App link I would like to redirect to my website (or any specific url) instead of https://www.facebook.com/games..... ?

Thanks in advance.

[image: Following this figure]

Comment: Well then you will have to remove your app from App Center.

Comment: @CBroe How could I do that ? I don't understand.

Comment: Add the website platform. Then it should link there.